# Check if user is authenticated in urls.py

Tags: python, ajax, django, authentication

Is it possible to do something like this in urls.py?

urls.py: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QVQ8BEvJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication checks should be performed in the view, that's where checks and security are ment to exist.

Apart from that you can decorate Class Based Views in urls to check for login, but the most common / sensible / usual approach is to make that check in the view.
If you are using Class Based Views then you could create a Mixin which checks if the user is authenticated, this combined with the tools Django Offers, allow you to redirect the user to the appropriate view (login, or if check is passed allow him to view the requested url).

If you are using function based views, then Django offers decorators for those functions to provide common "needs" of a web framework.

PS If you are using CBV's then django-braces has already a few wonderful mixins available for common tasks (Ajax, Security etc).

Comment: I understand but requests will be send via ajax, how about that?

I don't want to implement checking if user is authenticated for every method in view but do this globaly. From this is my idea with do this in urls.py

Comment: My approach to such scenarios is, create a seperate view (ajax_views.py) insert there the Ajax based Views, I tend to use django-braces which allows me to reuse any View in ajax terms, a global Mixin is used for user validation (something like core/mixins.py) which I can reuse in all my login based views.

Answer (score 1):

This is not right way to implement it. 
The best solution is to wrap your views with @login_requered decorator.

Example:

```
@login_required
def home_page(request):
     ...
```

You can specify in your settings.py LOGIN_URL where user will be redirected if not authorized.
Please read more [at django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#login-url)